# Why can't I open a Qt5 application via Eclipse CDT4?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, qt5, eclipse-cdt

I cannot launch my Qt application correctly using Eclipse (right click on the project, then **Run as > Local C/C++ application**) ; my program opens a command prompt for a microsecond then the console displays the `<terminated>` state. However I can open my application correctly by launching directly the .exe file. What is the reason for this behavior on Eclipse?

Here is my code (**QtTest.cpp**):

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPushButton hello("&Hello wo&rld!", 0);
    hello.resize(100, 30);
    hello.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (QtTest)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(QtTest QtTest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(QtTest Qt5::Widgets)
```

My OS is Windows 10, I generate my application using CMake.

Comment: How does your application locate the Qt DLLs? No experience with Eclipse, but in VisualStudio, I've to setup the environment, to add the folder with the Qt DLLs to the path for making debugging working properly, e.g. `PATH=%PATH%;C:\<install-folder-of-Qt>\Qt\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\bin`. Surely, I could've set this in my system env. settings as well but it's not the only one installed Qt on my box... (Btw. I use CMake as well to prepare the VS solution files but that doesn't change things in my case.)

Comment: Yes I've done that, I've added `D:\dev\Qt5\build` and `D:\dev\Qt5\build\bin` to my `Path` environment variable.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a thought. I've rarely issues with IDEs and Qt but mostly they are about not finding DLLs (directly after "the current working directory is not that what you expect").

Comment: This is difficult to find Eclipse CDT users on forums, everybody uses NotePad++ or Visual Studio to make code :) But my lab forces me to use that

Comment: A stupid idea: If your lab forces you to use Eclipse then there might be a tutor or somebody else with experience to provide a hint. I would attest you that your MCVE is well-done and shouldn't cause any esoterical issues (beside of the fact that you already got it running.) ;-)

Comment: In fact I've got a talented tutor but he doesn't know the origin of that problem